# Spring RequestMapping conflicts

Tags: java, spring, request

I have a `RequestMapping` that displays a grid, and another one for loading objects in grid.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/grid/{objType}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String displayGrid(Model model, @PathVariable("objType") String objType) {
    // some code here
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/loadGrid", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String loadGrid(Model model) {
     // returns a JSON
}
```

When i display the grid the url is like `../grid/User`

The problem is that after the grid is created and a request loadGrid is made, the request is mapped to `/grid/loadGrid` which is resolved by the first method instead of the second one.

Is there any way to make a request for `/grid` with nothing after it ?
Or any way to resolve this conflict ?

Comment: How is the request made. Show us that part of the code, there will be the error.

Comment: Is your concern that /grid/loadGrid should call the second method ?

Comment: Yes. I want /grid/loadGrid to call only the second method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collision isn't a problem; spring resolves exact matches first. (see the [source code of `AbstractHandlerMethodMapping`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java#L349))

Your problem is that you've incorrectly defined your mappings. If you define a `@RequestMapping` at the class level, all the method `@RequestMappings` will be prefixed with the defined value.

The following maps three endpoints: `/grid`, `/grid/{objType}` and `/grid/loadGrid`. Note that the `@RequestMapping` for `get()` defines no `value`, only its `method` because it inherits from the class-level annotation.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/grid")
public class GridController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get(Model model) {
        // ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{objType}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayGrid(Model model, @PathVariable("objType") String objType) {
        // ...
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/loadGrid", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loadGrid(Model model) {
         // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: did you test the code above for /grid/loadGrid if it calls the loadGrid() ? or ends up calling displayGrid() since 'loadGrid' satisfies the String conditon

Comment: Yes, it has been tested.