# Why must the second part of the RequestMapping value be different in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, servlets

I have 2 handler methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/my/handler", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void myHandler(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // implementation
}
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value="/my/handler/version2", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void myHandlerVersion2(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // implementation
}
```

When I made a POST request to `/my/handler/version2` it gave me a 405 error:

```
    
    405 Not Allowed
    
    405 Not Allowed
    nginx
```

But after I changed my second RequestMapping to `/my/version2/handler` and made a POST request to `/my/version2/handler`, it worked. Why was that?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154181/how-to-avoid-springs-requestmapping-paths-conflicts

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311207/spring-requestmapping-conflicts